# \printacronyms gives an extra line at end

Tags: spacing, acro

I used `acro` package with tabular style to print acronyms. When I did that, it added an extra line to the end of acronyms list, therefore `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` corrects the problem. However that extra line should not be added, which do not happen if you use a `description`-like environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{list-style=tabular} % commented gives the list style
\DeclareAcronym{UHF}{%
    short={UHF},
    long={Ultra High Frequency},
    }
\DeclareAcronym{RF}{%
    short={RF},
    long={Radio Frequency},
    }

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\ac{UHF}\ac{RF}


\printacronyms[heading=section]
%\vspace{-\baselineskip} % fixes spacing with 'list-style=tabular'

\section{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is an empty paragraph at the end but it's quite unclear where it comes from…

Comment: It does not exist when you use the lists. Is there any additional `\\' in the `tabular`/`longtable`/`tabularx` definition?

Comment: No there isn't. As I said: it's quite unclear where it comes from

Comment: The more I investigate the less idea I have where this is coming from… :(

Comment: I would suggest a temporary workaround, the same way I did in my MWE.

Comment: I think I found the cause. An update will follow soon. I'll provide an answer, then

Comment: Hi. That is a good new :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in v2.6e (2016/09/04):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}[2016/09/04]
\acsetup{list-style=tabular}

\DeclareAcronym{UHF}{
  short = {UHF} ,
  long = {Ultra High Frequency}
}
\DeclareAcronym{RF}{
  short={RF},
  long={Radio Frequency}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\ac{UHF}\ac{RF}

\printacronyms[heading=section]

\section{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it with `tabular` and it worked. But I tried it with `tabu` (following the example in the documentation) but it didn't work as expected. The gap between section head and the list itself is too huge.

Comment: If you believe there is something buggy please make a bug report with minimal example https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/

Comment: Ok. Added already.

Comment: @cacamailg Thanks. There is nothing `acro` can do. I added an example to [the issue you opened](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/84) that shows that the space is caused by `longtabu` itself. You could maybe use the `before` option when defining the style adding some negative vertical space.

Comment: Thanks. I added a code below which I think works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

With the code below it seems to work as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu,longtable}
\usepackage{acro}[2016/09/04]
\DeclareAcroListStyle{longtabu}{table}{
    table = longtabu ,
    table-spec = @{}lX@{},
    before={%
        \setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
    }
}   

\DeclareAcroListStyle{newtabular}{table}{
    table = tabular ,
    table-spec = @{}lp{.7\linewidth},
}

\DeclareAcronym{UHF}{
  short = {UHF} ,
  long = {Ultra High Frequency}
}
\DeclareAcronym{RF}{
  short={RF},
  long={Radio Frequency}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\ac{UHF} \ac{RF}

\acsetup{list-style=newtabular}

\printacronyms

\section*{Acronyms}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lp{.7\linewidth}}
  RF  & Radio Frequency \\
  UHF & Ultra High Frequency
\end{tabular}

\acsetup{list-style=longtabu}

\printacronyms


\section*{Acronyms}

\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
\begin{longtabu}{@{}lX@{}}
  RF  & Radio Frequency \\
  UHF & Ultra High Frequency
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```